# JAVA - how to read specific line then put it in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, readfile, java-io

Hi so i have this project that requires me to write the code in java lets say i have this txt file:

```
GoodTitle   Description
Gold        The shiny stuff
Wheat       What wheaties are made of
Wood        To make more ships
Spices      To disguise the taste of rotten food
Tobacco     Smoko time
Coal        To make them steam ships go
Coffee      Wakes you up
Tea         Calms you down
```

all i want to do is to put the left side of the text (goodtitle,gold,wheat,wood,etc) into an arraylist and the right side of the text(description,the shiny stuff) into another array list. this is my current code:

```
public void openFile(){
        try{
            x = new Scanner(new File("D://Shipping.txt"));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("File could not be found");
        }
    }
    public void readFile(){
    while (x.hasNextLine()){
        String a = x.next();
        x.nextLine();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (x.hasNext()){
            list.add(x.next());
        }
        System.out.printf("%s \n", list);
        }
    }
    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
```

probably it need some modification on readFile as i still confuse on how to do it. thanks in advance...

```
NOTE=I am not allowed to change the content of the txt file. 
     in my current code i still put the whole thing into 1 arraylist because i am unable to split them.
```

do i need toString method?because i have no idea how to do it. 
thanks in advance...

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a `Map<String, String>`

Comment: So what's a problem? Parse your string with something like String.split("\\s") or use StringTokenizer, then add tokens into separate lists..

Comment: @JoshM ,he wants two sepearte lists not a map

Comment: Maybe he wants parallel lists because he missed the chapter that tells him to try to avoid it.

Comment: Oh, Ok. Well, disregard my solution then. I will leave it posted as a later reference. :P

Comment: Or traverse the map and make parallel lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read the left side into one list and the right side into another.

This code isn't right because `x.next()` doesn't actually return one column. How could it know what one column is? But it should give you an idea of how to do it.

```
ArrayList<String> listL = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listR = new ArrayList<String>();
while (x.hasNextLine()){
    x.nextLine();
    if (x.hasNext()){
        listL.add(x.next());
    } else {
        listL.add("");
    }

    if (x.hasNext()){
        listR.add(x.next());
    } else {
        listR.add("");
    }
}
System.out.println(listL);
System.out.println(listR);
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider You might want to look more closely at the 2nd paragraph. I just added it so you wouldn't have seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use a `Map<String, String>`, perhaps you could try something like this:

```
public static Map<String, String> getContents() throws IOException {
    final Map<String, String> content = new HashMap<>();
    final Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("D://Shipping.txt"), "UTF-8");
    while(reader.hasNextLine()){
        final String line = reader.nextLine();
        final String[] split = line.split(" +");
        content.put(split[0], split[1]);
    }
    reader.close();
    return content;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    final Map<String, String> content = getContents();
    content.keySet().forEach(k -> System.out.printf("%s -> %s\n", k, content.get(k)));
}
```

I'd just like to note that this solution was programmed using Java 8, surely you will be able to modify it to a lower JDK level.

Comment: im a bit unfamiliar with map<string, string> but sure ill give it a try..thanks man